# Advanced System Care 9.3 showing hard-drive error in Windows 10 but

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, chkdsk

I have a weird problem Advanced System Care shows me that you have a Hard Drive Error but when I check it using Windows `chkdsk` command in Windows 10 CMD (using all parameters) it says fine no errors.

Moreover, Advanced System Care pretends to correct the error but then error remains the same after next scan!

How to correct that error if it is really there?

**Here is the error pic Advanced System Care is showing :-**

[image: Advanced System Care Hard-Drive Error PIC]

Comment: If you run chdsk and it finds errors, then you run it again, the errors in this case were already handled.

Comment: So this Advanced System Care is showing file error how to correct it? It pretends to correct itself but it doesn't . Running 'chkdsk' is useless it detects no errors. Thanks

Comment: run **chkdsk C: /f**

Answer (score -1):

Use of the program, which is called "Crystal Disk Info" from:
[CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html)

Comment: Show us print screen from Crystal Disk Info.

Comment: It shows everything is fine